# http-proxy-middleware, how to copy all/cookie headers

Tags: javascript, angular, http-proxy, browser-sync, lite-server

I am using lite server by John Papa with HTTP proxy middleware by chimurai
as a dev server.
the problem is with my session cookie, I cannot persist the session cookie that comes from the real server.
I saw this solution:
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/78

but I see no resemblance to my bs-config.js:

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = {
    port: 3003,
    server: {
        middleware: {
            1: proxy('demo/webservice/jaxrs', {
                target: 'https://localhost:8443',
                secure: false, // disable SSL verification
                changeOrigin: true   // for vhosted sites, changes host header to match to target's host
            }),
            2: require('connect-history-api-fallback')({index: '/index.html', verbose: true})
        }
    }
};
```

Does someone knows how to merge this two?

UPDATE: this is part of the response headers:

```
set-cookie:JSESSIONID=620083CD7AEB7A6CC5772AC800E673E3; Path=/appServer/webservice/jaxrs; Secure
strict-transport-security:max-age=31622400; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

UPDATE2:
I think my config should look like this:

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function relayRequestHeaders(proxyReq, req) {
    Object.keys(req.headers).forEach(function (key) {
        proxyReq.setHeader(key, req.headers[key]);
    });
};

function relayResponseHeaders(proxyRes, req, res) {
    Object.keys(proxyRes.headers).forEach(function (key) {
            res.append(key, proxyRes.headers[key]);
        });
};

module.exports = {
    port: 3003,
    server: {
        middleware: {
            1: proxy('/skybox', {
                target: 'https://localhost:8443',
                secure: false, // disable SSL verification
                changeOrigin: true,   // for vhosted sites, changes host header to match to target's host
                onProxyReq: relayRequestHeaders,
                onProxyRes: relayResponseHeaders
            }),
            2: require('connect-history-api-fallback')({index: '/index.html', verbose: true})
        }
    }
};
```

but now res.append is undefined :(

Comment: Can you provide the RAW response from the target? What's the `set-cookie` value in that RAW response?

Comment: I updated my original post. this is the session cookie: set-cookie:JSESSIONID=620083CD7AEB7A6CC5772AC800E673E3; Path=/appServer/webservice/jaxrs; Secure

Comment: Can you also provide the RAW request which is being fire to the server on port 3003?

Comment: Im using create react app and when i use the proxy middleware i get only a partial authentication token (Size is reduced) any reason for this?

Answer (score 6):

try it:

```
var cookie;
function relayRequestHeaders(proxyReq, req) {
  if (cookie) {
    proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', cookie);
  }
};

function relayResponseHeaders(proxyRes, req, res) {
  var proxyCookie = proxyRes.headers["set-cookie"];
  if (proxyCookie) {
    cookie = proxyCookie;
  }
};
```

It's working with lite-server

Comment: Thank you for this hint, It solved a similar issue I had with nodejs and http-proxy-middleware

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your localhost:3003 is configured; With or without `https:`...

Say you are using http://localhost:3000 (not https:);
The `Secure` cookie attribute from your target might be the cause for your browser to omit the cookie.

> 4.1.2.5.  The Secure Attribute
>
> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure"
> channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent).  When a
> cookie has the Secure attribute, the user agent will include the
> cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted over a
> secure channel (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS)

source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.5

Browsers may omit cookies based on the algorithm described in: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4

Try removing the `Secure Attribute` and see if that helps

Comment: when moving to http without the secure flag I do get the session. Does that mean that I can't use https or secure cookies with browser sync?

Comment: You still can. Just enable the `https` option in browser-sync: `browserSync({
    https: true
});` This way the secure cookie probably won't get rejected.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set up the proxy.
if (dev) {
  const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
  server.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://api.example.com/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
      // logLevel: 'debug',
    })
  )
}
```

This is my configuration. I think the point is with

```
cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
```

Answer (score 1):

B.Ma's answer give me a hint to solve my problem with the webpack-dev-server which probably uses the http-proxy-middleware under the hood to proxy the request. The problem comes with the httpOnly cookies and this approach solved it.
Here is my config that I used in the webpack.conf.js:

```
let myappSessionValidationCookie = '';

module.exports = {
    ...
    devServer: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:9000/',
        ...
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost/myapp',
                changeOrigin: true,
                onProxyReq: function (proxyReq) {
                    if (myappSessionValidationCookie) {
                        proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', myappSessionValidationCookie);
                    }
                },
                onProxyRes: function (proxyRes) {
                    const proxyCookie = proxyRes.headers['set-cookie'];
                    if (proxyCookie) {
                        myappSessionValidationCookie = proxyCookie;
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Some explanation for the configuration. I have a backend that is serving the app's api under the localhost/myapp/api/* and sets a httpOnly cookie that is for authentication purposes. That header (set-cookie) was not transferred by the proxy to the new location (localhost:9000/myapp/api/*) so the browser is not keeping it and all following requests were without this cookie and failed.
All the credits goes to B.Ma. Many thanks for the post!!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case setting `"cookieDomainRewrite": "localhost",` works. This allows the browser to setup correctly the cookies since the domain would match

Below complete config for `setupProxy.js` in React:

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
            cookieDomainRewrite: "localhost",
        })
    );
};
```